# Tables are getting refreshed after re-executing the application with EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder using derby

Tags: java, spring-boot, derby, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring Boot and Spring JDBC with Derby. Below is the code snippet to initialize the embedded Database.

```java
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        // no need shutdown, EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean will take care of this
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.DERBY) //.H2 or .DERBY
            .addScript("db/sql/create-db.sql")
            .addScript("db/sql/insert-data.sql")
            .build();
        return db;
    }
```

But when I am running the application the tables are getting dropped and created each time. So all the data inserted in last run was flushed. I don't want to drop the tables. How can I achieve this?

Comment: does your **create-db script.sql** contains drop statement ?

Comment: No. It doesn't contain drop statement.

Comment: posted the answer, please confirm if it works.

Answer (score 1):

set the below property in your application.properties/application.yml

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

As per spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties)

***spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto***

> DDL mode. This is actually a shortcut for the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"
>   property. Defaults to **"create-drop"** when using an **embedded database**
>   and no schema manager was detected. Otherwise, defaults to "none".

As you are using embedded database, it is defaulting to create-drop